# unable to edit data in reducer for put method

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I'm creating a mern app, and I'm trying to edit the data of the selected project. When I click on editing, the data are edited in the mongodb, and in express server logger, but not in redux logger response, I get the response of state before editing. I'm not sure what exactly is the problem..

example of data

```
{
_id:1,
title:'title',
description:"description"
}
```

When i edit `title` to value of `title edited`, it's edited in mongoDb, but not in redux logger action response. it state `title:'title'`. I can only get values of edited items after I refresh the page.

Reducer

```
case projectActions.UPDATE_PROJECT:
        {

            return { ...state, 
                      project:state.project.map( item =>
                           (item._id===action.payload.data._id) ? 
                               action.payload.data:item) 
                   }

        }
```

Action for update

```
function updateProjectAction(response){
    return {
        type:UPDATE_PROJECT,
        payload:response
    }
}

export function updateProject(id,updatedVal){
    return (disptsh, getState) => {
        return Project.editProject(id,updatedVal)
                      .then(response=>disptsh(updateProjectAction(response)))
                      .catch((error)=>disptsh(getError(error)))
    }
}
```

dispatching the edit action

```
this.props.actions.updateProject(this.props._id,{title:this.state.title})
```

Update express middleware

```
router.put('/api/project/:id',function(req,res,next){
    Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body, function(err, updatedProject){
        res.json(updatedProject)
    })
})
```

Comment: probably your logger goes before your middleware, that deals with mongodb

Comment: the logger works fine with both get and post method. but eventually it fires before the mongodb... any tips on how to deal with this? I tried to use axios directly in react, same issue. the data response shows up before database is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and based on [this article](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2936), I've found the problem resides in the `findByIdAndUpdate`, as the `new` option is false by default, and by extention it doesn't return the updated data.

To solve this, I had to set `{ new: true}` to be able to get the updated data.

```
router.put('/api/project/:id',function(req,res,next){
    Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body, { new: true} , function(err, updatedProject){
        res.json(updatedProject)
    })
})
```